# Sharepoint 2010 - locate new site that haven't been checked in

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

If a user create a new site and just saves is without checking the site in, where's the location?

I want to test what's happens if a farm administrator tries to publish a site that's not a "draft" or a published site. (got a custom "publish now"-button without having to go trough a workflow)

Comment: Please read the FAQ.  This type of question should go on sharepoint.stackexchange.com because it is related to SharePoint administration but not SharePoint programming.

Comment: There is no way to create draft sites in Sharepoint 2010. do you mean a Publishing Page?

Comment: @Luis I don't know exactly what it's called, but I just want do find the location of the "site" so a administrator can delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Sharepoint dot not support draft versions of sites, I think you mean List Items or documents that not have been checked in by your users.

To see those items you can use the Site Content and Structure facilities. Check this post:

http://arabic2000.com/blog/index.php/archives/364